# Proximal Mapping - Derivation of the Proximal Operator from the Resolvent of the Sub Differential

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, proximal-operators

[image]

I do not really understand the solution for this question. I do not understand how the zero vector was derived to be an element of the subdifferential and why g(u) is strongly convex. Any help and further elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know, from which book this comes?

Comment: I know this question has already been answered, but I want to comment on this technical detail :       $ \textbf{1}$. $2(z-u)=\nabla \|z-u\|^2$ is the same to say that the subgradient of $ \dfrac{1}{2} \| z-u \|^2$ is singleton with value $(z-u)$. $\\\textbf{2}.$ $\sum_i \partial f_i⊆\partial\left(∑_if_i\right)$ then $0\in \partial f(z)+\partial\dfrac{1}{2}\| z-u \|^2 \Rightarrow 0\in \partial \left(f(z)+\dfrac{1}{2}\|z-u \|^2 \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \in z + \lambda \partial f(z)$, and $x, z$ is a vector and $\partial f(z)$ is a set. Thus this means that $x-z \in \lambda \partial f(z)$, or $0 \in \lambda \partial f(z) + (z-x)$.
And then according to
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{z} \|z-x\|^2 = 2(z-x),
\end{equation}
we have 
\begin{equation}
0 \in \partial(\lambda f(z) + \|z-x\|^2).
\end{equation}

For the $g(u)$, since $g(u) = \lambda f(u) + \frac{1}{2}\|u-x\|^2$ which is the summation of convex function and strictly convex function, and thus it is strictly convex.

Comment: I didn't understand how it went from 0 ∈ λ∂f(z)+(z−x) to the next line of 0 ∈  ∂(λf(z) + 1/2 ||z-x||^2) @Ze-Nan Li

Comment: I have edited my answer.